# CORS issue in Container App that has custom domain with same base domain

Tags: cors, webpack-module-federation, azure-container-apps, angular-module-federation

I have Angular app deployed in two container apps with custom domain as below

```
app1.dev.myproduct.mydomain.com  
app2.dev.myproduct.mydomain.com
```

Here app1 is the shell container and it calls app2 using [Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/).
Even though they are in the same domain *.mydomain.com there is CORS issue.

I managed to workaround by adding CORS Allowed Origin as app1.dev.myproduct.mydomain.com in to app2 and also Allowed Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

But, how can I avoid this CORS without adding Allowed Origin?
Is it necessary to add Allowed Origin even if both the custom domain for the container app is in same base domain?

Comment: Different subdomains imply different Web origins, hence your need for configuring CORS. See examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin